# What method do I use to find the probability of this event?

Tags: probability

So the question is that there's a test for HIV. There's a false positive rate of 0.025 and a false negative rate of 0.08. Let's say a particular patient has a probability of testing positive for HIV of 0.005. The patient gets tested and it's positive. What are the chances that the patient actually has HIV? I'm not sure what formula to use to find that probability. The answer they gave was 0.156 so how did they get to that answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical application of Bayes formula, 
\begin{equation}
P(B|A)=P(A|B)P(B)/(P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|\bar{B})P(\bar{B})).
\end{equation}
Here $A$ is testing positive, $B$ is having HIV, and $\bar{B}$ is not having HIV. $P(A|B)$ is the true positive rate, the complement of the fpr .08. $P(A|\bar{B})$ is the false positive rate .025. Substituting the numbers you give, $P(B|A)=.92*.005/(.92*.005+.025*.995)=0.1560645.$